# Calculating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x| e^{(-|x|/a)^b} \,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am in a bit of a struggle with this one and any tips would be helpful.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x| e^{(-|x|/a)^b} \,dx &= 2 \int_{0}^\infty x e^{-x^b/a^b} \,dx
\end{aligned}
$$
I've tried the substitution $t = (\frac{-x}{a})^b$ however with no solution. Best regards,

Comment: Put $t=(x/a)^b$; then you’ll get something which can be evaluated using the Gamma function (assuming some mild conditions on $a,b$).

Comment: Does it equal to $\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta} \Gamma(2/\beta)$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $-(|x|/a)^b$?

Comment: @BreeZeriNoo Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$t=\frac{x^b}{a^b}$$ then
$$x^b=a^bt  $$$$x=at^\frac{1}{b}$$

and
$$\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a}{b}\frac{t^\frac{1}{b}}{t}\mathrm{d}t$$
Now the integral is equal to
$$\frac{2a^2}{b}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^\frac{2}{b}}{t}e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t$$
And this is rewrited by gamma function, which is
$$\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^s}{t}e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t$$
If $s$ is positive integer
$$\Gamma(s)=(s-1)!$$
so the integral is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x| e^{(-|x|/a)^b} \,dx &= 2 \int_{0}^\infty x e^{-x^b/a^b} \,dx=\frac{2a^2}{b}\Gamma(\frac{2}{b})
\end{aligned}
$$
If $\frac{2}{b}$ is positive integer
$$\frac{2a^2}{b}\Gamma(\frac{2}{b})=\frac{2a^2}{b}(\frac{2}{b}-1)!$$

Comment: How did you get $(-1)^b=-1$?